# How to get full list of UTF8 charset in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I would like to add a test suite which will run over the entire Unicode charset. Is there a way to get the full list of Unicode chars? Most online resources talk about how to encode and decode but didn't find useful material talking about how to get the full list.

Comment: UTF-8 is an encoding, not a charset. UTF-16 and UTF-32 and some of the alternative encodings for Unicode which is a real charset

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*TL;DR:* You might want to skip to the "Visible Code Points" section further down.

---

#### All Code Points

Every [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) character ([code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point)) can be encoded in [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). As Wikipedia says it:

> UTF-8 is capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid character [code points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) using one to four one-byte (8-bit) code units.

Unicode comprises 1,114,112 code points in the range 0<sub>hex</sub> to 10FFFF<sub>hex</sub>.

So, to get all UTF-8 characters:

```java
// Build string with every Unicode character
int[] codePoints = new int[0x110000]; // 0 - 0x10FFFF
for (int i = 0; i < codePoints.length; i++)
    codePoints[i] = i;
String allChars = new String(codePoints, 0, codePoints.length);

// Convert to UTF-8
byte[] allUtf8Sequences = allChars.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Print statistics
System.out.printf("Code points: %d = 0x%1$x%n", codePoints.length);
System.out.printf("Java chars : %d = 0x%1$x%n", allChars.length());
System.out.printf("  Surrogate pairs: %d = 0x%1$x%n", allChars.length() - codePoints.length);
System.out.printf("UTF-8 bytes: %d = 0x%1$x%n", allUtf8Sequences.length);
System.out.printf("  Average bytes per code point: %.2f%n", (double) allUtf8Sequences.length / codePoints.length);
```

*Output*

```
Code points: 1114112 = 0x110000
Java chars : 2162688 = 0x210000
  Surrogate pairs: 1048576 = 0x100000
UTF-8 bytes: 4384642 = 0x42e782
  Average bytes per code point: 3.94
```

---

#### Visible Code Points

Note that not all code points are currently defined by Unicode. Use [`Character.isDefined(codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDefined-int-) if you want to limit to defined characters.

You also might not want to skip control characters and whitespace characters. To skip all of those, and only check visible characters, we can check the character type using [`Character.getType(codePoint)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getType-int-):

```java
// Build string with visible Unicode characters
int[] codePoints = new int[Character.MAX_CODE_POINT + 1];
int count = 0;
for (int codePoint = 0; codePoint < codePoints.length; codePoint++) {
    switch (Character.getType(codePoint)) {
        case Character.UNASSIGNED:
        case Character.CONTROL:     // Cc
        case Character.FORMAT:      // Cf
        case Character.PRIVATE_USE: // Co
        case Character.SURROGATE:   // Cs
        case Character.SPACE_SEPARATOR:     // Zs
        case Character.LINE_SEPARATOR:      // Zl
        case Character.PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR: // Zp
            break; // Skip
        default:
            codePoints[count++] = codePoint;
    }
}
String chars = new String(codePoints, 0, count);

// Convert to UTF-8
byte[] utf8bytes = chars.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Print statistics
System.out.printf("Code points: %d = 0x%1$x%n", count);
System.out.printf("Java chars : %d = 0x%1$x%n", chars.length());
System.out.printf("  Surrogate pairs: %d = 0x%1$x%n", chars.length() - count);
System.out.printf("UTF-8 bytes: %d = 0x%1$x%n", utf8bytes.length);
System.out.printf("  Average bytes per code point: %.2f%n", (double) utf8bytes.length / count);
```

*Output*

```
Code points: 143679 = 0x2313f
Java chars : 231980 = 0x38a2c
  Surrogate pairs: 88301 = 0x158ed
UTF-8 bytes: 517331 = 0x7e4d3
  Average bytes per code point: 3.60
```

Comment: Please note that some code points are not valid on it's own - i.e. surrogate pairs...

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yeah, I realized that too, and was in the middle of adding to the answer when you commented.

Comment: Now it's a great answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detail and code sample. It does help me a lot to but there are some places I am not fully understanding.

1. Unicode comprises 1,114,112 code points and Character.MAX_CODE_POINT is obviously smalled than it, which means java does not support full unicode chars?

2. The java buildin `Character.isDefined` method states "Determines if a character (Unicode code point) is defined in Unicode." but obviously it filters out some codepoints, which seems to be contradicted to the method description/statement?

Comment: actually, I take back the first question. I misread the output from your example.

Comment: @dashenswen If you look at the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/43cb25339b55/src/share/classes/java/lang/Character.java#l5701) for `Character.isDefined(int codePoint)`, you'll see **`return getType(codePoint) != Character.UNASSIGNED;`**, and the javadoc says *"A character is defined if at least one of the following is true: - It has an entry in the UnicodeData file. - It has a value in a range defined by the UnicodeData file."* where the range is the 0 - 0x10FFFF Unicode code point range.

Comment: thank you for the reply. I read some additional artifacts and it helps me to understand the code sample. Accept the answer!